# Change link underline color & not font color (bottom-border is not working across all browsers)

Tags: css, colors, hyperlink

Changing the border-bottom attribute along with removing text-decoration creates the colored underline in some browsers (I can vouch for FF 5 and 6 for sure). But other browsers (at least Safari & Chrome) don't display any line.

For example of the problem, see utsarotaract.org (there is a link in the bottom paragraph of the index page).

Since I've seen this work other places, I'm assuming that some of my CSS is clashing but I'm stumped as to where exactly the problem is.[image: What the user is seeing (no underline on "this form" @ the bottom)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the size of your border. Change your `0.5px` border to `1px` instead and it will work. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/tw16/WcrNA/

```
.content a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #A80532; /* instead of 0.5px */
    color: #000022;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: I have a user on Chrome who still cannot see the underline. Any suggestions?

Comment: Attached a screen shot of what they are seeing.

Comment: @dan: They probably have a cached version and need to refresh the page. Because, as you can see from the test case, it works in all browsers. Let me know if it still isn't working, otherwise please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use:

```
<a><span>I'm a link</span></a>
```

with the following CSS:

```
a {
  color: blue;
}
span {
  color: green;
}
```

The alternative being using a border-bottom. It's also a cross-browser solution. You'll just have to set its padding/margin/line-height to make it consistent from a browser to another.

Comment: I would really rather not have to add a span tag with each a tag though.